# Silverlight set ListBoxDragDropTarget children/items from code behind

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have an app which builds up list boxes programmatically from the code behind.
I would like to make the elements contained in the list boxes draggable.

I know this can be achieved in the xaml by the use of a ListBoxDragDropTarget by using the following xaml code :

```
<toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget mswindows:DragDrop.AllowDrop="True">
    <ListBox Width="200" Height="500" x:Name="FromBox" DisplayMemberPath="FullName">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
```

However i need to achieve this from the code behind rather than through xaml. Is there a way of setting the drag drop target from the code behind?

I cant seem to find a property which will allow the dragDropTarget to be set. Something like:

```
 Dim target As New ListBoxDragDropTarget

 target.children.add(listbox) / target.items
```

Not sure if it's possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to work on my opinion. Try target.AllowDrop = true then add your elements as you have shown on your sample (target.Children.Add(FromBox)) . Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However not sure if we had different version of Silverlight but the add property of target did not exist. Figured it out, ill post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the problem in the end.

I ended up setting the ListBoxDragDropTarget.content to the list box. (Which contained multiple objects)

```
  target.Content = listBox
```

I then added the target to the wrapPanel, then finally added the wrapPanel to my main grid.

```
 wp.Children.Add(target)
 grdApps.Children.Add(wp)
```

The drag / drop functionality is now working!